# How to integrate a Database file into a BlackBerry application?

Tags: database, blackberry

I have got a database file with some info which I need to go along with the application. How to do that?

Comment: Do you want to store the data on the actual device or just access the data (e.g. through a website)

Comment: I want to store the data on the device itself.

Comment: I want the database file to go into a specific location in SD card when the applications is installed in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the database to the resource folder and on launching the app, write that to the SD card or device memory. Then read the data from the  memory.

Comment: can you please elaborate that?

Comment: Include the db file in the project resources. Then in run time extract it from resources and save to SDCard.

To extract a resource use Class.getResourceAsStream(String name) method.

A starting point in saving files on BB could be this guide: Code sample: Writing text to a file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831345/how-to-include-a-sqlite-database-with-a-blackberry-application

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option you have (I may be wrong!) is SQLLite for Blackberry.  It was introduced from version 5.0 of Blackberry Software.  See [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/SQLite_overview_701956_11.jsp)

If you are working with a version earlier than that you can use Persistant Storage but this isn't a relational database so will be a bit tricker.

Comment: sorry I think you have misunderstood the question. I have got all the sqlite part sorted out. I have got the .db file in my hand too. All I want to know is how could I put that db file into the sd card of the user when he installs the app. Or if possible access the db file from within the application's resource folder itself, if so how?