# How to include a SQLite database with a Blackberry application?

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry

In my application, I have some static data that I want to display in one screen. So I imported the data to a database and added that to the SD card. Now the app is working fine on the simulator. But when I created the cod/alx file and installed the app to the device, the db is missing. Can anyone suggest the way to include this db inside the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the db file in the project resources. Then in run time extract it from resources and save to SDCard.

To extract a resource use [Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method.

A starting point in saving files on BB could be this guide: [Code sample: Writing text to a file](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Writing_text_to_a_file_1219767_11.jsp).